# What could be the reason of this error on the website?

Tags: html, web, webserver, cpanel, http-status-code-403

What could be reason for the 403 forbidden connection error. Why the website is not safe on a college network. what is making it harmful.

[403 Forbidden Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzQOA.jpg)

Comment: http/1.1 403 forbidden connection close

Answer (score 0):

"The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason. "

this is a good resource for you i feel!

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message

best of luck mate!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the page on another connection.  This thing has happened to me before but the reason was that I was trying to access a school website and it told me that my location had been blacklisted.  The reason why was that I was using a vpn.  It may be that the website is set to only have people from a certain country/region access it.  You might try playing around with vpn location settings and see if any of them work.  Other than that good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It would really depend on the kind of URL filtering or walled garden system the college use.

It may operate with a 'whitelist' of approved sites and suffixes. It may also filter the keywords of sites that are requested and use logic to actively block or allow websites. If your site hosts content that is deemed 18 + or content not suitable for an education network then it would be blocked too.

Depending on how strict the college are you may also find that they filter out personal blogs, gaming sites even social media...

See these two links - https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/walled-garden and https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/cyberpedia/what-is-url-filtering

Just pulled them off google real quick but they get the point across.

To get around you could use a proxy, but you may get in trouble if that is considered an abuse of the network which may result in disciplinary action.

Best advice I could give you is to use a smartphone or something with some 4G data and access that way. Then you don't need to worry about your college filtering, or even watching what you do!